# Detect UI changes to @Published property

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple SwiftUI App that fetches App Settings using a REST API call and makes it available to the UI using an `@ObservedObject` with a `@Published` property. I have several `Toggle` views that bind to the `@Published` property.

Each time a `Toggle` is "toggled", I need to upload the change to the server. So I added a `didSet` observer to the `@Published` property and although this works, the `didSet` property observer also gets fired when I initially fetch the settings from the server.

How can I avoid firing the `didSet` observer when initially setting the `@Published` property with settings fetched from the server?

Comment: Would you show and demo code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you are describing is correct. When you load the setting with your REST API and then set it to the `@Published` the value gets set, and your function is getting called.

You can add a variable to your class, which stores if the fetch is completed. When you fetched all your results, you set it to true and only then allow didSet function to be executed.

```
//Set your fetched data previous 
var fetchCompleted : Bool = false

//after your api call and fetch result success
fetchCompleted = true

.didSet() 
{
   if (fetchCompleted)
   {
   //allow override from variables and store new setting
   }
}
```

Make sure you set your variables with the fetched data first, and then set fetchCompleted to true. Otherwise didSet will called after and fetchCompleted would already be true.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without code shown, but you could add an if-condition in your didSet which prevents it from executing your upload, when the Published value is "nil" (initial).